# When Extending Array map is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extend Array so that I can add in my own additional functionality. I've read that extending Array.prototype can be dangerous, so I am trying to do it the correct way with class inheritance.

The issue I'm running into is that map is undefined. I can obviously work around this but I don't understand why as I am extending Array and therefore should have It's functionality?

```
export default class Array2 extends Array {
  constructor(items) {
    super(...items);
  }

  addOne() {
    return this.map((x)=>{
      return x+1;
    })
  }
}

let arry2 = new Array2 ([9, 1, 4, 0]).addOne();
console.log(arry2);
```

I expect to have Array2 (4) [10, 2, 5, 1] logged into the console but instead i get the following error thrown.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**Edit**
Removing the constructor seems to fix the issue but does not explain why it fails when a constructor is present. especially when the constructor is just calling super.

Comment: does adding `public` keyword before the `addOne()` definition change anything?

Comment: Nope, but the addOne function works. I can loop through the values with a for loop, I just wanted to be functional and return a new array instead of editing the existing one.

Comment: you don't need to extend Array to do this. i would question why you're even making a separate adding function when a simple call to .map would work just fine.

Comment: This is funny. It looks like the internal `map` function fails... [Proof](http://jsbin.com/fogoqulefo/edit?console)

Comment: @Cruiser this is just a very simplified example of what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging with

```
constructor(items) {
    console.log(...arguments);
    super(...items);
}
```

may shed some light on this. In `map`, a new array is created, of type `Array2` - and it is calling the constructor with the desired length, `4` - just like a standard `Array` would support this. However, you are spreading the argument `items` into the super call, which will try to iterate the value `4` - and clearly it's not iterable, failing with "*`4[Symbol.iterator]()` is not a function*" (ok, that's what the message *should* have been).

To avoid this, use the standard constructor signature and just pass any arguments directly to super as they are. Or simply omit the `constructor`, as the default constructor will do this pass-through for you.

Use

```
export default class Array2 extends Array {
  addOne() {
    return this.map((x)=>{
      return x+1;
    })
  }
}

const array2 = Array2.from([9, 1, 4, 0]).addOne();
const array3 = Array2.of(9, 1, 4, 0).addOne();
console.log(array2, array3);
```

That's what `of` and `from` were made for.

Comment: What you have said makes sense in that it is a bad error description. Unfortunately running your code produces an error: Uncaught TypeError: Array2.from is not a constructor

Comment: Oops, I missed to remove the `new`.

Comment: This works now which is clever as i'm learning. Using the from method is there anyway I can pass other parameters into the constructor.

Comment: Yes, you can overload the constructor to use more constructors, but you always have to support the signature where a single integer is passed. (Not sure whether you even have to pass it through to `super`, but you must at least not cause an exception :P)

Comment: Reference to what this helped solve: https://github.com/StueyKent/svg-to-createjs-path

Comment: @Michael It simply shouldn't. It must not violate the original contract (signature) of `Array`, i.e. it must be usable in every place where `Array` can be used, and that includes `new Array(42)`. If you want to do something really different, then maybe you shouldn't write a subclass but a wrapper. Also consider using `Array2.of(…)` and `Array2.from(…)` instead of the constructor - what's wrong with them?

Answer (score 0):

You used the spread operator on the wrong place.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

I guess you would like to reach more parameters into the constructor function.

```js
        class Array2 extends Array {
          constructor(items) {
            super(items); //here is the problem
          }

          addOne() {
            return this.map( (x) => {
              return x+1;
            } );
          }
        }




        let arry2 = Array2.from([2, 1, 4, 22]).addOne();
        console.log("arry2", arry2);
```

Comment: Yes, eventually expanding on the constructor is the aim. Your code does not do what is expected though.

Comment: You need to remove the **new** and my example will work.
If thought your constructor have had a unknown reason for me. So i don't touched it.

`Array2.from([9, 1, 4, 0])` will work