# Using .splice method in subclass of Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, subclass, mutators

I am trying to create a subclass of javascript's Array. I want to initiate subclass with array-type argument and add a method to remove an element from the array (subclass).

My code looks like this:

```js
class CustomArray extends Array {
        
  constructor(array) {
    console.log('Initiating array:', array)
    super(...array);
  }

  remove(element) {
    let index = this.indexOf(element);
    if (index > -1) {
      return this.splice(index, 1);
    } 
    return [];
  }

}

var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var list = new CustomArray(a)
console.log('list:', list);
console.log('remove:', list.remove('c'));
console.log('list:', list);
```

The problem is that when I call [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it removes element from array, but also returns array of deleted elements, actually it returns new instance of my subclass CustomArray, which should be initiated with argument of array type, but .splice() initiates it with arguments of integer type.

Here is an example of what I think happens when I call [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

Let's say we have instance `list` of `CustomArray` class initiated with argument `['a','b','c','d','e']` and then we call method `list.remove('c')`. (Just like in code snippet).
Method `remove` of `CustomArray` class checks the index of `c` is in array `['a','b','c','d','e']`, which is `2` and then calls `method this.splice(2,1)` which should remove 1 element at index 2 in array `['a','b','c','d','e']`. Method `splice` removes element `c` form array, but also returns something like `new CustomArray(1)` because one element was removed form array so it tries to create array of length 1, but that failes because class `CustomArray` is expectiong array.

I want to prevent `splice` method from initiating a new instance of `CustomArray` class and instead return normal array (an instance of Array object).

[Jsbin link.](https://jsbin.com/boqomuj/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: FWIW, I just noticed a bug in the code in my answer which I've fixed (missing `++index;` line).

Comment: `CustomArray` or `CostomArray`?

Comment: Thanks for the fix on `++index`, but I used for loop instead of while. And it is  CustomArray, I edited that in the question.

Comment: [Your `constructor` is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525859/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to prevent `splice` method from initiating a new instance of `CustomArray` class and instead return normal array (an instance of `Array` object).

Then you need to create a different method with a different name. The semantics of `splice` are [clearly and precisely defined](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.splice); they form a contract for the `Array` type. Having your `CustomArray` violate that contract would mean it isn't an `Array` anymore, it's something *array-like*, and shouldn't extend `Array`.

Since your method is called `remove`, that's fine; if you want `remove` to return `Array`, not `CustomArray`, you just need to implement the logic yourself:

```
remove(element) {
  let index = this.indexOf(element);
  if (index > -1) {
    const newLength = this.length - 1;
    while (index < newLength) {
        this[index] = this[index + 1];
        ++index;
    }
    this.length = newLength;
    return [element];
  } 
  return [];
}
```

---

Alternately, of course, make `CustomArray`'s constructor work correctly when called by the various `Array.prototype` methods. (The one you have in the question works just fine, other than logging something you don't expect with `console.log`.)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible have `splice` return a standard array -- so without it calling your constructor. It is by changing the [`@@species` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@species) of your custom class, which determines which constructor will be used. But be aware that this will not only affect `splice`, but also *all* other methods that would create a new instance, including `map`, `filter`, `slice`, ...

You can change the `@@species` property by overwriting the corresponding static getter:

```js
class CustomArray extends Array {
  static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; } // <-----------

  constructor(array) {
    console.log('Initiating array:', array)
    super(...array);
  }

  remove(element) {
    let index = this.indexOf(element);
    if (index > -1) {
      return this.splice(index, 1); // Now calls Array constructor, not CustomArray
    } 
    return [];
  }

}

var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

var list = new CustomArray(a)
console.log('list:', list);
console.log('remove:', list.remove('c'));
console.log('list:', list);

// Some examples of effects on other methods
console.log(list.map(x => x) instanceof CustomArray); // false
console.log(list.filter(x => 1) instanceof CustomArray); // false
console.log(list.slice() instanceof CustomArray); // false
console.log(list.concat() instanceof CustomArray); // false
// Other methods, that do not return a new instance, are not affected:
console.log(list.reverse() instanceof CustomArray); // true
console.log(list.sort() instanceof CustomArray); // true
```