# Call native functions from inherited system array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a new class called OrderedArray which extends a system Array:

```
export class OrderedArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    constructor(elements: T[], private _comparer: (a: T, b: T) => number) {
        super(...elements);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, OrderedArray.prototype);
        this.sort(this._comparer);
    }

    /**
     * Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order according to a key.
     * @override
     */
    public thenBy(keySelector: (key: T) => any): OrderedArray<T> {
        return new OrderedArray(
            this,
            composeComparers(this._comparer, keyComparer(keySelector, false))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in descending order, according to a key.
     * @override
     */
    public thenByDescending(keySelector: (key: T) => any): OrderedArray<T> {
        return new OrderedArray(
            this,
            composeComparers(this._comparer, keyComparer(keySelector, true))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Converts the OrderedList back to an array to be able to chain other actions to.
     */
    public toArray(): T[] {
        let returnArray = new Array();
        returnArray.addRange(this);
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Which transpiles down to ES5:

```js
var extendStatics = function(d, b) {
    extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
    return extendStatics(d, b);
};

function __extends(d, b) {
    extendStatics(d, b);
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
}

var OrderedArray = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(OrderedArray, _super);
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    function OrderedArray(elements, _comparer) {
        var _this = _super.apply(this, elements) || this;
        _this._comparer = _comparer;
        Object.setPrototypeOf(_this, OrderedArray.prototype);
        _this.sort(_this._comparer);
        return _this;
    }
    /**
     * Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order according to a key.
     * @override
     */
    OrderedArray.prototype.thenBy = function (keySelector) {
        return new OrderedArray(this, composeComparers(this._comparer, keyComparer(keySelector, false)));
    };
    /**
     * Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in descending order, according to a key.
     * @override
     */
    OrderedArray.prototype.thenByDescending = function (keySelector) {
        return new OrderedArray(this, composeComparers(this._comparer, keyComparer(keySelector, true)));
    };
    /**
     * Converts the OrderedList back to an array to be able to chain other actions to.
     */
    OrderedArray.prototype.toArray = function () {
        var returnArray = new Array();
        returnArray.addRange(this);
        return returnArray;
    };
    return OrderedArray;
}(Array));
```

This allow me to do: `array.orderBy(m => m.field).thenBy(m => m.field2);`

This will return an `OrderedArray` object, which in the console looks like:
[image: console output]

Which *looks* like an array, even prototypes as such, but when calling native array functions like `slice`, the following error occurs:
`Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object`

Now I have to call `toArray()` after the last orderBy function call to convert it to a proper array, but is this necessary? Is there a way to call native array functions on my object?

Comment: Given this is typescript, please show us the code that it was transpiled to (and possibly the typescript config). It should work in native ES6, it should not work in other environments. `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, OrderedArray.prototype);` looks extremely sketchy.

Comment: Oh, actually it shouldn't work in ES6 either. [You don't support the overwritten constructor signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525859/1048572), which is a must when subclassing `Array`. The error message ("length, a number, is not iterable/spreadable") is even fancier though than in the old question :-)

Comment: You can define the `@@species` property on your class like this: `static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; } `  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56181665/5459839). I think this could be considered a dupe.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean it's not supposed to work? I'm using it in production now and I haven't had any issues, I added the ES5 transpiled code to my post.

Comment: @RogerFar I mean that calling native array methods (that instantiate another array) is not supposed to work in ES6 given how you've written your constructor.