# Calling splice on an extended Array causes an Error and I have no idea why

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I call `Remove` in my class it throws an error when it comes to `this.splice`. Please note, `this.index` works fine. Do you have any idea why? And do you have a workaround?

```cs
export class DefaultReorderableList<T> extends Array<T> implements ReorderableList<T> {

    constructor(items: Array<T>=[]) {
        super(...items);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
    }
    
    Remove(item: T | ((element:T)=>boolean) ): void {
        let index: number = -1;
        if(item instanceof ((element: T)=> Boolean)){
            for(let i:number = 0, l:number = this.length; i<l; i++){
                let foo:(element:T)=>boolean =item as (element:T)=>boolean;
                if(foo(this[i])){
                    index=i;
                }
            }
        }
        index = this.indexOf(item as T);
        if (index >= 0) {
            this.splice(index,1);
        }
    }

    SwapToPrevious(index: number): void {
        if(index == 0){
            return;
        }
        if(index < 0 || index >= this.length){
            throw new Error("Out of Range");
        }
        let indexedValue = this[index];
        this[index] = this[index -1];
        this[index-1]= indexedValue;
    }


    SwapToNext(index: number): void {
        if(index == 0){
            return;
        }
        if(index < 0 || index >= this.length){
            throw new Error("Out of Range");
        }
        let indexedValue = this[index];
        this[index] = this[index + 1];
        this[index + 1]= indexedValue;
    }

}
```

Now in JavaScript you can run it here: https://jsfiddle.net/La3pqj1v/

```
class DefaultReorderableList extends Array{

    constructor(items =[]) {
        super(...items);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);
    }
    
    Remove(item) {
        let index = -1;
        index = this.indexOf(item); // works
        if (index >= 0) {
            this.splice(index,1); // does not work
        }
    }

    SwapToPrevious(index) {
        if(index == 0){
            return;
        }
        if(index < 0 || index >= this.length){
            throw new Error("Out of Range");
        }
        let indexedValue = this[index];
        this[index] = this[index -1];
        this[index-1]= indexedValue;
    }


    SwapToNext(index) {
        if(index == 0){
            return;
        }
        if(index < 0 || index >= this.length){
            throw new Error("Out of Range");
        }
        let indexedValue = this[index];
        this[index] = this[index + 1];
        this[index + 1]= indexedValue;
    }

}

let testClass = new DefaultReorderableList();
testClass.push("a");
testClass.push("b");

console.log(testClass[0])
testClass.SwapToPrevious(1); // works
console.log(testClass[0])
testClass.Remove("b"); // does not work
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @imvain2 depends on runtime

Comment: @Bergi now I had time to add a runnable example

Comment: Btw, `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);` should be unnecessary in any ES6-compatible environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `splice` returns an array with the removed items. This array is of the same species (read: subclass) as the method receiver (`this` value), i.e. a `DefaultReorderableList` in your case. And `splice` instantiates a `new DefaultReorderableList(1)` with the length, as any `Array` constructor should support it. Your constructor is breaking the contract to implement that interface, and causes an exception when trying to iterate the number in `super(...items)`.

See also [When Extending Array map is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525168/1048572).

Fix it by removing your constructor entirely (or reimplementing the default `constructor(...items) { super(...items); }`). If you want to create an instance and pass an array to initialise it, use `DefaultReorderableList.from([…])`.