# Subclass of array doesn't seem to inherit the methods of the superclass

Tags: javascript, oop

I have been working on a small Matrix class that extends Array and calls the array constructor via `super`. Some of the methods that I've becoming accustomed to using on arrays, such as map and slice, cause on error (`RangeError: Invalid array length`) when I use them inside the subclass methods on `this` and seem to point to the call to the Array constructor as the ultimate culprit. I was initially super confused by this until I learned that when you use slice or map that a new array object is created. What I still don't get is why slice and map don't see to work on a subclass of an array. Isn't the point of creating a subclass so that you have all of the methods and functionality from the parent class? I did finally manage to get something to work, but it involves converting `this` to an Array, which seems weird. Here is an example of what I did.

```
rows() {
        let rowArray = [];
        for (let k=0; k<this.nrows; k++){
            let start = k * this.ncols; 
            let stop = start + this.ncols;
            rowArray.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(Array.from(this), start, stop));
        }
        return rowArray;
    }
```

So, my question is is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? i.e. is there an intelligent way to call map and slice on a subclass of Array and the other methods associated with an Array object?
I initially thought that I could use `Array.prototype.slice.call(this, ...)` instead of simply calling `slice` on `this` but I got the exact same error. Here is the entire class:

```
class Matrix extends Array {

    constructor (nrows, ncols, elem = (x, y) => undefined) {
        if (!Number.isInteger(nrows) || 
                !Number.isInteger(ncols) || 
                nrows < 0 || 
                ncols < 0) {
      throw new TypeError("Invalid nrows or ncols argument");
    }
    const size = nrows * ncols;
        super(size)
        this.nrows = nrows;
        this.ncols = ncols;
        this.shape = [nrows, ncols];
        
        // fill entries using elem function
        for (let k=0; k < this.length; k++) {
            let position = this.idx(k);
            this[k] = elem(position[0], position[1]);
        }
    }
    
    idx(k) {
        // completes row by moving across columns
        return [Math.floor( k / this.ncols), k % this.ncols];
    }
    
    // TODO
    static fromArray(){
        return null;
    }
    
    rows() {
        let rowArray = [];
        for (let k=0; k<this.nrows; k++){
            let start = k * this.ncols; 
            let stop = start + this.ncols;
            //console.log(prettyMatrix.slice(start, stop));
            rowArray.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(Array.from(this), start, stop));
        }
        return rowArray;
    }
    
    prettyPrint() {
        let prettyMatrix = Array.apply(null, Array(this.length));
        let padding = this._getMaxLength();
        prettyMatrix.forEach((x, idx) => 
                                                  prettyMatrix[idx] = 
                                                    this._padElement(this[idx], padding));
        // print single row at a time
        for (let k=0; k<this.nrows; k++){
            let start = k * this.ncols; let stop = start + this.ncols;
            //console.log(prettyMatrix.slice(start, stop));
            console.log("| " + prettyMatrix.slice(start, stop).join(", ") + " |");
        }
        return null;
        
    }
    
    // helper function for prettyPrint
    _padElement(x, size) {
        let str = "";
        let delta = size - x.toString().length;
        if (delta >= 0){
            for (let k=0; k<delta; k++){
                str += " ";
            }
            str += x.toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return str;
    }
    
    // helper function for prettyPrint
    _getMaxLength() {
        let lengths = new Array(this.length);
        super.forEach((x, idx) => lengths[idx] = x.toString().length);
        return Math.max(...lengths);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "*a small Matrix class that extends Array*" - a matrix is not an array. Do not use subclassing. [Use composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) for that.

Comment: Please show us your subclass, in particular the overwritten constructor. I bet this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64687402/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525168/1048572.

Comment: @bergi I respectfully disagree with this. A Matrix is simply a 2-d array.

Comment: Well but the JS `Array` is a 1-d array, and your representation of a 2-d array doesn't fit as a subclass of that. In particular, the constructors are incompatible. It might work if you represent `Matrix` as an array of arrays.

Comment: The constructors do seem to be incompatible, but JS supports have arrays as elements of arrays. The reason I didn't format this is an array of arrays was 1. I'm following an example from Eloquent Javascript 3rd edition that uses a 1d array and 2. I wanted to use inheritance, if for no other reason than so I use all the concepts from Chapter 6 of this book.

Comment: "*The constructors do seem to be incompatible*" - well they **are** incompatible. And `this.slice(start, stop)` does create a new `Matrix`, not an `Array`, passing the new `length` as the first and only constructor parameter.